# Onchange event for html drop-down list

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

i am trying to control a set of drop-down menus,by changing the first menu then all the others will have the first menu selected item as selected.

In my example,what i want to achieve is : when changing the selected value of the 'select for All' then the rest should be set to that value.

i hope i made it clear.

thanks in advance.

Check the below screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED!!!!** Try this link [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/markipe/bHxym/3/)

```
 $("#sortedby").change(function () {
      $("select").val($(this).val());
  });
```

**UPDATED!!!!**

Comment: looks great,now what if my options are in array?

Comment: Works Perfectly on JSFIDDLE,but on my localhost it doesn't,any idea what could be the reason??!!

Comment: Did you use jquery library in your localhost?

Comment: One last question.
how can i use that function for line-by-line changing??

Comment: something like:
    'for($v = 0 ; $v <= $linenr ; $v++)
    {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "$('#sortedby0";
    echo $linenr;
    echo "').change(function () {";
    echo "$('select').val($(this).val());";
    echo "});";
    echo "</script>";
    }'

Comment: add id to your tr and call it like this sample $("#sample_id select").val($(this).val());

Comment: can't thank you enough,but here is what i got in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmedadil1000/LGtbm/8/embedded/result/)
but on the localhost,nothing is changing,any idea what could be the reason???

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a jQuery implementation (change your selectors accordingly):

```
$(function() {
    $('select.select-all').change(function() {
        $('select', $(this).closest('tr')).val(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you change it to reflect your own selectors/classes?

Comment: i did,my selectors names : all,CodesLists1

Comment: Those don't look like valid selectors.  If they're classes, there would be a dot (.) in there somewhere.